# Output LRESULT to console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to output text from Notepad window to console and it's always 0.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
int main()
{

    HWND hwnd = (HWND)0x0031019C; // Window Handler of Notepad
    char szBuf[4096];
    HWND hwndEdit;
    LRESULT result;

    hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, L"Edit", NULL); // Class for edit box
    result = SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(szBuf) / sizeof(szBuf[0]), (LPARAM)szBuf);

    cout<<"Contents: \n"<<result;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried `print_f`, but it outputs unreadable characters:

```
printf( "Contents: %s\n", result, szBuf );
```

Comment: I have checked your code but in my case `0x0031019C`. It doesn't seems that the handle is of Notepad. Please try `GetWindowtext(hwnd, szbuf, 1024)` before `FindWindowEx()`. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you probably have a little bit of a mismatch happening.

Based on the `L"Edit"`, you seem to be doing a Unicode build (otherwise, you'd get an error message about not being able to convert an `wchar_t const[5]` to `LPCSTR`, and the code wouldn't compile.

If you do a Unicode build, however, WM_GETTEXT is going to write Unicode data to your buffer, so you need to prepare for and use Unicode instead of narrow characters for your buffer.

For convenience, I've modified it a little to find Notepad instead of using a hard-coded Window handle.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define elements(b) (sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]))

int main() {

    HWND hwnd; // Window Handler of Notepad
    wchar_t buf[4096]={0};
    HWND hwndEdit;
    LRESULT result;

    hwnd=FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, L"Notepad", NULL);
    hwndEdit=FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, L"Edit", NULL); // Class for edit box
    result = SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, elements(buf), (LPARAM)buf);

    printf("%S", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I built with:

```
cl /DUNICODE whatever.cpp user32.lib
```

Then I did a quick test that printed out exactly the text I'd typed into Notepad. To verify the result, I then edited the text in notepad, ran it again, and it printed out the modified text.

Comment: `wchar_t` is a key to the problem! Thanks! How about outputting in another language? Just tried to type in Russian and output is blank.